# Use vim shortcuts in TeXstudio

Tags: latex, texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio to edit my *.tex files. Is there any way to add vim shortcuts to TeXstudio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/540/) on their Sourceforge tracker and an [issue](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/155) on GitHub, there is currently no way to add vim keybindings to TeXstudio.

You can use other vi supported IDE such as [VIM-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) or [Kile](https://kile.sourceforge.io/) (Which uses [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/) as editor).

Edit:
I ended up using VSCode for using latex with latex-workshop and vim extensions. Very convenient for me.

Comment: Thanks, I work with latex workshop and vim extension in the VSCode.

Comment: For basic latex (more precisely mathjax supported latex) there is also obsidian that has latex and vim support. There is an obsidian extension that allows configuring a vimrc file and i am currently trying out the latex suite extension which adds text expansion functionality for quickly typing latex which I am liking so far.

Comment: I also read some comments about vimtex but I have not tried it yet

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I work with `latex workshop` and  `vim` extension in [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Edit: Another suggestion for Github users. Use GitHub actions. :)

Here is an example for anyone who might be interested ([Latex_Github_aciton](https://github.com/HosseinBeheshti/CV))

Comment: Instead of replying to my answer, SO way is to set my answer as correct and comment on it if you have any :)